# How do a user's download, played, viewed music pages ranking algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

i have a music pages website, and users can download, play, and view those pages, and I want to make a ranking page for this.

this ranking depend on those music's download, play, and view times. 3 attributes added together and call a new name is HOT pt.

I want this ranking page rank all music page with a point which is limit in 100.

example: I have 3000 pages .and the top 3 pages there has HOT pt with 300,500,700. and i want these 3 pt run within 100.like this below:

Top 1 : test1 99.34
top 2 : test2 94.21
top 3 : test3 89.64

so, how can i get a algorithm like this?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the HOT ranking? Or you already have it and you are asking how to normalize it to [0,100]?

Answer (score 0):

If you already made your ranking system to get those points, then you only need to normalize it to 0-100.

For example:

```
page id   points      
1         500
2         300
3         700
4         200
```

Then you need the page with the maximum points (700 in this case), divide all points by it and multiply by 100.

```
page id   points            points[0-100]   
1         500 / 700 * 100    71.43
2         300 / 700 * 100    42.86
3         700 / 700 * 100   100.00
4         200 / 700 * 100    28.57
```